# moment a day and hours ago

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have these dates

promoEnd = ISODate("2020-10-20T10:00:00.000Z")
Today is 2020-09-28T01:00:00.000Z")

If I use

```
moment.duration(now.diff(promoEnd)).humanize()
```

My result is 21 days.

How Can I have 21 days and X hours in the same result?
I need even to vice-versa,
21 days and 10 hours ago, for example

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like you need to use humanize if you want some specific output, you could probably do something like:

```
const duration = moment.duration(now.diff(promoEnd));
const result = `${duration.days()} days and ${duration.hours()} hours`;
```

Note that it could be weird for zero days / hours/